# How to create laravel filter without button submit

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I want to create some filter in dashboard admin panel, this filter using select dropdown, with option today, last 7 days, and last 30 days, and I won't use button submit for get the data. I use this condition

```
    if (request()->ajax()) {
            if (!empty($request->filter)) {
                if ($request->filter == 1) {
                    $today = array(
                        $purchase_order = PurchaseOrder::whereDate('date_of_purchase', '=', Carbon::now())->get()->count(),
                        $sales_order = SalesOrder::whereDate('date_of_sales', '=', Carbon::now())->get()->count(),
                        $revenue = SalesOrder::whereDate('date_of_sales', '=', Carbon::now())->get()->sum('grand_total'),
                        $product_sales = ProductSalesOrder::leftJoin('product', 'product.product_id', '=', 'product_sales_order.product_id')
                                        ->leftJoin('sales_order', 'sales_order.sales_order_id', '=', 'product_sales_order.sales_order_id')
                                        ->whereDate('sales_order.date_of_sales', '=', Carbon::now())
                                        ->selectRaw('harga_beli * qty_order AS total_modal')->get()->sum('total_modal'),
                    );
                    echo json_encode($today);
                } elseif($request->filter == 2){
                    $a_week = array(
                        $purchase_order = PurchaseOrder::whereDate('date_of_purchase', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))->get()->count(),
                        $sales_order = SalesOrder::whereDate('date_of_sales', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))->get()->count(),
                        $revenue = SalesOrder::whereDate('date_of_sales', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))->get()->sum('grand_total'),
                        $product_sales = ProductSalesOrder::leftJoin('product', 'product.product_id', '=', 'product_sales_order.product_id')
                                        ->leftJoin('sales_order', 'sales_order.sales_order_id', '=', 'product_sales_order.sales_order_id')
                                        ->whereDate('sales_order.date_of_sales', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
                                        ->selectRaw('harga_beli * qty_order AS total_modal')->get()->sum('total_modal'),
                    );
                    echo json_encode($a_week);
                }
                elseif ($request->filter == 3) {
                    $a_month = array(
                        $purchase_order = PurchaseOrder::whereDate('date_of_purchase', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))->get()->count(),
                        $sales_order = SalesOrder::whereDate('date_of_sales', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))->get()->count(),
                        $revenue = SalesOrder::whereDate('date_of_sales', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))->get()->sum('grand_total'),
                        $product_sales = ProductSalesOrder::leftJoin('product', 'product.product_id', '=', 'product_sales_order.product_id')
                                        ->leftJoin('sales_order', 'sales_order.sales_order_id', '=', 'product_sales_order.sales_order_id')
                                        ->whereDate('sales_order.date_of_sales', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))
                                        ->selectRaw('harga_beli * qty_order AS total_modal')->get()->sum('total_modal'),
                    );
                }

            }
        }
```

what shall I do in laravel blade?, it will be using ajax for getting the data?, or something

Comment: I would use ajax and create an api endpoint where you can pass filter_id to the endpoint to return a json response, then change your data with the response data.  (this is easy in something like VueJS,  are you using vue?)

Comment: @Cameron no, I use Laravel Blade. Monolithic Laravel

Comment: if you don't mind a page reload you can make your route use an optional param, then use the same route to "post" with the filter id and return the same view.   if you want ajax, make an API endpoint to return the data but you will need to build the display with JS (from the response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="filterData()">
   <option value="1">Today</option>
   <option value="2">Week</option>
   <option value="3">Month</option>
</select>

<script>
  function filterData() {
  let filter = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;

  // Here you need to ajax call the method by post request with filter value

  }
</script>
```